# Telethon doesn't work with channel ID but works with username

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

Hi i want ot try to receive a notification every time a channel send new messages, for this i have created this snippet:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = XXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXX'
channelId = '-100XXXXXXXX'



client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats = [channelId]))

async def main(event):
    

    
 # print(event.raw_text) 
    

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

But i don't understand why work only if use username in channelID, i want use ID because some channel are private.

I used the bot "@username_to_id_bot" in telegram to retrieve the ID through the link of channel.

When use username work fine but when i use the ID o channel return this error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-10' coro=<UpdateMethods._dispatch_update() done, defined at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py:399> exception=ValueError('Cannot find any entity corresponding to "-100XXXXXXXX"')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 458, in _dispatch_update
    await builder.resolve(self)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\common.py", line 99, in resolve
    await self._resolve(client)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\newmessage.py", line 93, in _resolve
    await super()._resolve(client)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\common.py", line 103, in _resolve
    self.chats = await _into_id_set(client, self.chats)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\events\common.py", line 33, in _into_id_set
    chat = await client.get_input_entity(chat)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 437, in get_input_entity
    await self._get_entity_from_string(peer))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 574, in _get_entity_from_string
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "-100xxxxx"
```

I have tried to pass also entities like this example without success:

https://ingrom.com/python/47397/telethon-get-channel-id

can someone help me to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats = [channelId]))
```

you should use `entity` instead of `chats`, like

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(entity = channelId, message = "message you need to send"))
```

Comment: Cannot find entity in the constructor